# Alternative to QGraphicsDropShadowEffect for Frameless Window Shadow

Tags: c++, qt

Like many software applications today, I want my program to have a frameless window that still has a drop shadow to make it fit better with the OS. The first step was to set the window flags to `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` to remove the frame. But the trickier part is adding a drop shadow to the outside of the window. I opted to add a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` to a smaller base widget that holds everything and make `QMainWindow` transparent by setting the attribute `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` to true.

This seems to be a good solution for me, until I added a `QSizeGrip` to enable resizing of the window. Every time the window gets resized, a paint event is called and the `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` needs to be recalculated. This results in SUPER choppy resizing and a big performance hit.

Are there any alternatives to `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` that has better performance?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Okay I edited my question to hopefully follow the guidelines better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with my own solution that I haven't seen on SO yet.

I ended up making 12 png images that when arranged in a set of layouts, gives the illusion of a drop shadow. I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but what I did was split each side into 3 parts. This accounts for many different ways the drop shadow could be set up (offset and corner rounding)

Here's an exaggerated diagram:

[image: shadow_example]

The red areas are QLabel's with pixmap icons aligned to the outer corners. The purple areas are QLabel's with repeating background images. The red areas sizes are fixed but the purple areas can expand freely as set via min/max sizes and layout stretching. The top and bottom edges are horizontal layouts and the left and right edges are vertical layouts.

This works very well for my use case and solved all the choppy problems :)